NavController crashing in OutlineButton
So, i have a OutlinedButton and for some reason when there is another code besides
navController.navigate("HomeScreen")

my application crashing on starting with  this error:
Process: com.rendev.fooddelivery, PID: 23827
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.rendev.fooddelivery.screens.RegisterScreenKt: 
void com.rendev.fooddelivery.screens.RegisterScreenKt.RegisterScreen(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, 
androidx.navigation.NavController, androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int, int) failed to verify: 
void com.rendev.fooddelivery.screens.RegisterScreenKt.RegisterScreen(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier, 
androidx.navigation.NavController, androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int, int): [0x1072] copy1 v0<-v268 type=Reference: 
androidx.compose.ui.Modifier cat=1 
(declaration of 'com.rendev.fooddelivery.screens.RegisterScreenKt' appears in /data/app/~~Z0Ucuhnop6JLnikZX1mHFw==/com.rendev.fooddelivery-Try7BmzgN67_EkBMtIOofQ==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
                                                                                                        
at com.rendev.fooddelivery.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:52)
                                                                                                        
at com.rendev.fooddelivery.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:51)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$32$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:694)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$32$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:693)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$32.invoke(NavHost.kt:693)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$32.invoke(NavHost.kt:674)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:803)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:792)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedEnterExitImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:771)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:774)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:757)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt.AnimatedContent(AnimatedContent.kt:816)
                                                                                                        
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:646)

when there is no navController.navigate("HomeScreen") in onClick, everything runs fine, also for some reason there is no such problem in other OutlineButtons
OutlineButtonCode:
@Composable
fun OutlineButtonElement(
    navController: NavController,
    firstNameText: String,
    lastNameText: String,
    eMailText: String,
    passText: String,
    context: Context,
    checkState: MutableState<Boolean>,
    borderColor: Color,
    tint: Color
) {
    OutlinedButton(
        enabled = true,
        onClick = {

            val passwordError = validatePassword(passText)

            if (
                firstNameText == ""
                || lastNameText == ""
                || eMailText == ""
                || passText == ""
            ) {
                makeText(
                    context,
                    "Please fill in all the details",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return@OutlinedButton
            }

            if (passwordError != null) {
                makeText(
                    context,
                    passwordError,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return@OutlinedButton
            }

            val namesPattern = Regex("\"/^((?:\\p{Ll}|\\p{Lu}){2,30}\\s?){2,4}\$/g\"")
            if (
                firstNameText.contains(namesPattern)
                || lastNameText.contains(namesPattern)
            ) {
                makeText(
                    context,
                    "First or Last name contains digits/special symbols",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return@OutlinedButton
            }


            if (!(android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(eMailText.replace(" ", ""))
                    .matches())
            ) {
                makeText(
                    context,
                    "E-mail is not valid",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return@OutlinedButton
            } else Log.d("E-mail", "Email is valid")


            if (!checkState.value) {
                makeText(
                    context,
                    "Please agree with the Privacy Policy & Terms Of Use",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                return@OutlinedButton
            }


            data class Person(
                val firstName: String,
                val lastName: String,
                val email: String,
            )

            val database =
                Firebase.database("")
            val myRef = database.getReference("users")

            auth = Firebase.auth
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(eMailText, passText)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        navController.navigate("HomeScreen")
                        val eMail = eMailText.replace(".", "_").replace("#", "_")
                            .replace("$", "_").replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_")
                        val person =
                            Person(firstNameText, lastNameText, eMailText)
                        myRef.child(eMail).setValue(person)
                        makeText(
                            context,
                            "Registered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    } else {
                        makeText(
                            context,
                            "Registration failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
        },
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, color = borderColor),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
            containerColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
            .height(45.dp),
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.registered),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(30.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = tint
        )
        val textColorMain = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.White else Color.Black
        Text(
            text = "Register",
            color = textColorMain,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
        )
    }
}

MainActivity code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            FoodDeliveryTheme  {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    Background()
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "RegisterScreen",
                    ) {
                        composable(
                            route = "RegisterScreen",
                            enterTransition = {
                                fadeIn(
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        800, easing = LinearEasing
                                    )
                                ) + slideIntoContainer(
                                    animationSpec = tween(800),
                                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right
                                )
                            },
                        ) {
                            RegisterScreen(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding), navController = navController)
                        }

                        composable(
                            route = "LoginScreen",
                            enterTransition = {
                                fadeIn(
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        800, easing = LinearEasing
                                    )
                                ) + slideIntoContainer(
                                    animationSpec = tween(800),
                                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Up
                                )
                            },


                        ) {
                            LoginScreen(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding), navController)
                        }
                        composable(
                            "ForgotPasswordScreen",
                            enterTransition =
                            {
                                fadeIn(
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        800, easing = LinearEasing
                                    )
                                ) + slideIntoContainer(
                                    animationSpec = tween(800),
                                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left
                                )
                            },
                        ) {
                            ForgotPasswordScreen(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding), navController)
                        }
                        composable(
                            "HomeScreen",
                            enterTransition = {
                                fadeIn(
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        800, easing = LinearEasing
                                    )
                                ) + slideIntoContainer(
                                    animationSpec = tween(800),
                                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Down
                                )
                            } ,

                        ) {
                            HomeScreen(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding), navController)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to clean project, then build again, didn't help, tried move navcontroller to another function and then call it, didn't help

Are you trying to run a Compose Test? Can you please clarify what the content of RegisterScreenTestKt exactly is?

Sorry, mixed up errors(took the old one), i was trying to run a test file to see maybe some code in my main file didn't work, but code RegisterScreenTestKt is almost the same as my main RegisterScreen is, the only difference is some code which is not related to this problem

Still, could you make sure that in Android Studio you are actually running your app, not the test? And then if it still crashes, post the correct error log. Also please edit your post and include how you obtain the navController for your OutlinedButton.

Yes, i am running my app, not the test, edited my original post and provided all needed code, RegisterScreen is basically a big function with all my ui elements in it, so only OutlinedButtonElement function
